# Beginner at intents

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Can anyone spot what is wrong with this code? It's the first time I have used intents:

```
Intent intent = new Intent( this,XmlParserActivity.class);

String Postcode = returnedAddress.getPostalCode().toString();

intent.putExtra("postcode", Postcode);
```

and in my parser I have:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

String Postcode = intent.getStringExtra("postcode");

URL url = new URL("http://new.myweather2.com/developer/forecast.ashx?uac=gcV3ynNdoV&output=xml&query=" + Postcode);
```

Please note that my gps is working, I have tested it

Logcat:

```
04-01 21:07:25.514: E/AndroidRuntime(19408): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-01 21:07:25.514: E/AndroidRuntime(19408): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-01 21:07:25.514: E/AndroidRuntime(19408):    at weather.app.WeatherApplicationActivity.onLocationChanged(WeatherApplicationActivity.java:116)
04-01 21:07:25.514: E/AndroidRuntime(19408):    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:228)
04-01 21:07:25.514: E/AndroidRuntime(19408):    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:160)
04-01 21:07:25.514: E/AndroidRuntime(19408):    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:176)
04-01 21:07:25.514: E/AndroidRuntime(19408):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-01 21:07:25.514: E/AndroidRuntime(19408):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
04-01 21:07:25.514: E/AndroidRuntime(19408):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4293)
04-01 21:07:25.514: E/AndroidRuntime(19408):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 21:07:25.514: E/AndroidRuntime(19408):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-01 21:07:25.514: E/AndroidRuntime(19408):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
04-01 21:07:25.514: E/AndroidRuntime(19408):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
04-01 21:07:25.514: E/AndroidRuntime(19408):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What's happening, did you log any value to see what you get ?

Comment: Hope so you have solved your problem

Comment: You have a null pointer exception: E/AndroidRuntime(19408): java.lang.NullPointerException 04-01 21:07:25.514: E/AndroidRuntime(19408): at weather.app.WeatherApplicationActivity.onLocationChanged(WeatherApplicationActivity.java:116), can you specify which line is this?

Answer (score 1):

According to your log, you have a null pointer exception on the line 116 of WeatherApplicationActivity.java.

Check this line, you should have a statement of the form A.B where A is null.

It could something like a().b.c().d where something at the left of a dot is null : either a() or a().b or a().b.c() is null

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure to use the second part of the code (in XmlParserActivity) in the onCreate method ?

It should work. And log more values to see what happens.

Comment: yes the second part is onCreate. Log.e(MY_DEBUG_TAG, "cannot retrieve postcode"); --- isnt working quite new to android and debugging

Comment: I have added my logcat to my question though

Answer (score 0):

The first code should be something like this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent( YourCurrentClassname.this,XmlParserActivity.class);

String Postcode = returnedAddress.getPostalCode().toString();

intent.putExtra("postcode", Postcode);
```

And to receive the value :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

String Postcode = intent.getExtras(FirstClassName.postcode);

URL url = new URL("http://new.myweather2.com/developer/forecast.ashx?uac=gcV3ynNdoV&output=xml&query=" + Postcode);
```

Comment: the `FirstClassName` is the name of the activity from where you are calling the Intent.Same with the `YourCurrentClassname`.

Comment: String Postcode = intent.getExtras(FirstClassName.postcode);
 this line is getting an error: postcode cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: Define this before the `OnCreate` and after the class start,i.e. after the first `{` in the First Class or the Calling Activity where you defined Intent : `public static final String postcode="your.package.name._clicked";` where substitute your package name properly.Try it

Comment: btw what does the _clicked do anyway?

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to get intent extras as below?  plz also log the extras bundle and see if you are getting correct key-val

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
if(extras !=null) {
     String PostCode = extras.getString("postcode");
}
```

Comment: I tried this it also didnt work. Im not very good a logging as im new this and my lecturer doesnt even know...

Answer (score 0):

This code is perfect, nothing is wrong with it.
You need to cut & paste a little more; in particular, do you use

```
startActivity(intent);
```

after setting up the intent?

Comment: The intent tells what you wish to do: start XmlParserActivity.class - then you actually do it: startActivity(intent).

Comment: So where would I put that? in the xml parser activity?

Answer (score 0):

Your "onLocationChanged" method will surrond with try-catch(NullPionerException) If you didn't get force close than this method' s variable and another variable in use method check.

Answer (score 0):

If you are usin `"putExra"` then in second activity use `"getExtra"`...!